# Looping dataset matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, dataset

Im doing some statistical analysis on multiply dataset but it seems really stupid hardcoding everything, so i was wondering if it's possible to make a loop for a dataset, the code i have is this:

```
dsA = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',7);
dsB = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',8);
dsC = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',9);
dsD = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',10);
dsE = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',11);
dsX = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',12);
dsY = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',13);

%Testing differences in median after 0,5 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_1] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x0_5Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 0,5 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'A_0,5_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_1);
title('Differences in median after 0,5 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]


%Testing differences in median after 1 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_2] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x1Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 1 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', '73_1_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_2);
title('Differences in median after 1 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]


%Testing differences in median after 1,5 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_3] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x1_5Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 1,5 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', '73_1,5_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_3);
title('Differences in median after 1,5 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]


%Testing differences in median after 2 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_4] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x2Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 2 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'A_2_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_4);
title('Differences in median after 2 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]


%Testing differences in median after 2,5 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_5] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x2_5Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 2,5 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'A_2,5_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_5);
title('Differences in median after 2,5 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]


%Testing differences in median after 3 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_6] = kruskalwallis(dA.x3Sec,dA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 3 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'A_3_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_6);
title('Differences in median after 3 sec for Concentration A')
```

And i need to do that to dataset A to Y, and hardcoding that just seems stupid... But i have tried to make a loop like i do when im working with images but i can't make it work when i try with datasets, does anyone have an idea of how to do that? 
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You have difficulties to write a loop because you are using variable names like `stats_A_3` or `dsA` which have the index encoded into their variable name. To develop a loop  version you have to refactor the code and remove such hard-coded indices. Start with two "iterations" like below and modify your code to have everything which differs between the iterations dependent on the variable `index`. You are finished when you have modified your code in a way that both blocks are identical but still do the same as previously.

```
%first iteration
index=1
t=index/2
dsA = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',7);
%Testing differences in median after 0,5 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_1] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x0_5Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 0,5 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'A_0,5_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_1);
title('Differences in median after 0,5 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]
%second iteration
index=2
t=index/2
dsB = dataset('XLSFile','RING 29 deg.xlsx','Sheet',8);
%Testing differences in median after 1 sex for A
[p,t,stats_A_2] = kruskalwallis(dsA.x1Sec,dsA.Code_1);
title('Differences in median after 1 sec for Concentration A')
print(gcf, '-dpdf', '73_1_sec.pdf');
figure;
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(stats_A_2);
title('Differences in median after 1 sec for Concentration A')
[nms num2cell(m)]
```

Some tools you will need to achieve it (Check the documentation if you don't know them):

- a cell array which replaces the `stats_A_1` to `stats_A_6` matrices
- `sprintf` to generate your file names
- [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Comment: I agree with structure that are simpler imho like a ds(1).data plus ds(1).stats and having iteration on each data set.

Comment: @R.Bergamote: You are right, a `struct` is the better choice for the stats. I did not read up the documentation for `kruskalwallis` and just picked a `cell` which stores anything.